# Regarding c++ object creation

Tags: c++

In the program below:

```
using namespace std;
class c1;
class c2;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   **c1 obj;
   c2 obj_c2 = obj.method1();**
   return0;
}
class c1
{
public:
  c2 method1()
  {
     c2 obj1;
     return obj1;
  }
};
class c2
{
public:
  int method2()
  {
    return 1;
  }

};
```

Inside main function, two lines of code are giving error. I could not compile.

Comment: We can have a look ourselves, sure. But it would be nice if you could actually post your errors within the question. Makes it all a bit easier to follow.

Comment: What's the point of the two asterisks on the second line of `main`?

Comment: @daknok_t He's trying to highlight those two lines as the lines that give him the errors.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the actual error description.

Answer (score 5):

You can't define a variable of an incomplete type. The definition must be visible before main (and `c2` before `c1`, if you define member functions inside the classes):

```
class c2 {
    // ...
};

class c1 {
    // ...
};

int main() {
    // ...
}
```

Also, in the future, always include the error in your question.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that you reordered the definitions of `c2` and `c1`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the two classes before you can use them as full types:

```
class c2
{
public:
  int method2()
  {
    return 1;
  }

};

class c1
{
public:
  c2 method1()
  {
     c2 obj1;
     return obj1;
  }
};

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   c1 obj;
   c2 obj_c2 = obj.method1();
   return 0;
}
```

A forward declaration does not cut it in this case, since you're not only declaring pointers, but actually try to instantiate object of those types.

However, I suggest you move your class declarations inside header files.

By the same reasoning, you need to define `c2` before `c1`, as `c1` needs to use the complete type `c2`.

Comment: @Muthu not just a forward declaration, but move the full declaration before you use the classes.

Comment: `class X;` is a declaration. `class X {};` is a definition. Member functions might not be defined yet, but the type itself is.

Answer (score 1):

`c1` and `c2` are incomplete types when you try to use them in `main`. Move their declarations (a.k.a bodies) before `main`. You are missing a space after the `return` in `main`.

I assume neither `**` nor `'` are part of the actual program.